# Какой css framework использовать для мобильного шаблона

Tags: css, laravel, framework

Здравствуйте. Есть задача: сделать мобильную версию сайта. Т.к. я ни разу не верстал мобильные версии, я даже не представляю какой фреймворк использовать. Хотелось бы в идеале что то типа мобильной версии алиекспресс. В стиле материал как приложение.
Подскажите есть ли подобный фреймворк? Или вообще какой нормальный фреймворк есть под мобильную верстку?

Comment: Никогда не верстал? Верстай ручками, начинать с фреймворков - верный путь упустить начальные истины, что отольётся в будущем.

Comment: Я имел ввиду не верстал шаблоны под моб девайтсы (не респонсив,а именно под моб девайсы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
мобильная верстка
material
```

Предлагаю Вам ознакомится с Material Design Lite от Google. Полностью адаптивен, чётко выдержан стиль Material, много компонентов. Гугл на нём часть своих сайтов написали. Лицензия - apache2
[ссылка](http://getmdl.io).